# Waterfall QA testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, qa-developer

As a QA learner I want to know about some methods. Now I am learning about waterfall testing methodology. Need to know details about the testing process of waterfall methods. I have learnt some topic from net & I have understood about it. I need to know details about waterfall testing. If you are following waterfall methodology or you have good idea on it so please you can provide me. I have some questions please see below:

1. What is waterfall testing?
2. What are variation about the methods?
3. Which topics are important to know before learning waterfall methods?
4. How can I start it?
5. Where from will I get basic knowledge & also learn about it?

And also others related topic about it.

If you have any advice about it or any edition so please inform me.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as "waterfall testing". The term "waterfall" is used for one approach to the entire software development lifecycle.

See the [generic Wiki article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model).

That being said, test design techniques (and most test-related topics) will remain relevant, regardless of the specific process in your company.

I would recommend the [ISTQB Foundation level](http://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/foundation-level/foundation-level-content.html) which covers every aspect of testing and also the main types of development cycles.

Answer (score 2):

As answered above there is no such thing as "waterfall testing". 
Waterfall Model is a software development methodology. There are various other methodologies also.
[image]

All design technique have their own pros and cons. which methodology to follow, depends on what strategy and processes are followed in ur organization.

U can go through the book by Rex Black for ISTQB. Also there are many other good blogs u can read to enhance your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

It is not "Waterfall testing" , The term "waterfall" is used for one approach to the entire software development lifecycle.

The Waterfall Model was first Process Model to be introduced. It is also referred to as a linear-sequential life cycle model.  It is very simple to understand and use.  In a waterfall model, each phase must be completed fully before the next phase can begin. This type of model is basically used for the for the project which is small and there are no uncertain requirements. At the end of each phase, a review takes place to determine if the project is on the right path and whether or not to continue or discard the project. In this model the testing starts only after the development is complete. In waterfall model phases do not overlap.
 [image]

Main Benefits of waterfall model is :

- This model is simple and easy to understand and use.
- It is easy to manage due to the rigidity of the model – each phase has specific deliverables and a review process.
- In this model phases are processed and completed one at a time. Phases do not overlap.
- Waterfall model works well for smaller projects where requirements are very well understood.

and , You can will get basic knowledge & also learn about from here: http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/agile-waterfall-hybrid-model/